# Editing sudoers in OS X (10.7)

Tags: macos, sh, sudoers

I've got a script (written by my predecessor) which successfully edits the sudoers file on a Mac running OS X 10.6; it goes like this:

```
#!/bin/sh

if [ -z "$1" ]; then
    export EDITOR=$0 && sudo -E visudo
else
    echo "%staff ALL=NOPASSWD: /sbin/shutdown" >> $1
fi
```

However, when run on a Mac running 10.7, instead of adding the line to the sudoers file, it launches visudo "interactively". It does not seem to enter the "else" clause at any point. I suspect that the appropriate syntax of line 4 ("export...") has changed, but I can't seem to find out how. Any pointers?

Since someone will ask: We have an elaborate (and admittedly, somewhat silly, but necessarily so) forced-reboot schedule for patching. If a user has not rebooted willfully by the deadline, an application will launch with a  5 minute countdown (or the option to reboot immediately) at which point the 'sudo shutdown -r now' command is issued. For my sanity's sake, please don't ask me to defend the nature of this arrangement. It is outside of my control.

Comment: --previous comment removed; disregard--

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`visudo(8)` has this to say:

> There is a hard-coded list of one or more editors that visudo will use set at compile-time
>   that may be overridden via the editor sudoers Default variable. This list defaults to
>   "/bin/vi". Normally, visudo does not honor the VISUAL or EDITOR environment variables
>   unless they contain an editor in the aforementioned editors list. However, if visudo is
>   configured with the --with-env-editor option or the env_editor Default variable is set in
>   sudoers, visudo will use any the editor defines by VISUAL or EDITOR. Note that this can be
>   a security hole since it allows the user to execute any program they wish simply by setting
>   VISUAL or EDITOR.

I suspect that's what you're running into here.

Comment: I agree. I'm going to be looking into this; however, why it worked in 10.6 but not 10.7 is a mystery. It's further complicated by the fact that 10.6 is a comprehensive, monolithic image in our environment, whereas 10.7 is more of a roll-up. It could be that our 10.6 image has some other adjustments made that would allow for the use of EDITOR.

Comment: Further testing - on my 10.6 machine, I was able to export EDITOR=/path/to/script, echo to verify, and then run sudo visudo - all went as expected (the sudoers file was modified as expected). I did the same on 10.7, echo to verify, and yet when I run sudo visudo, the EDITOR env var is most definitely ignored (it opens in vi). Your theory is confirmed.

Answer (score 2):

`if [ -z "$1" ];` is a common idiom checking if no arguments were given to a script.  When called *without arguments*, your script will take the first path, launching the editor (which, in this case should be this script itself).  *Given a file name* as an argument, the `else`-branch is taken and a line is appended to the file non-interactively (in `visudo` context).

Assuming that the script is called externally without arguments, sudo started clearing the EDITOR environment variable, or (as @twalberg noted) visudo now ignores EDITOR.

To fix, adjust the sudoers file to keep EDITOR, and either allow any program as editor by setting `env_editor`, or add the script (and any other scripts editing the sudoers file) to the `editor` variable.

```
Defaults    env_keep += "EDITOR"
# UNSAFE
#Defaults   env_editor
# better
Defaults    editor = "/usr/bin/vi:/path/to/script" # ... possibly more
```

If you do not want to do that (or can't do that non-interactively) and it is safe to assume that simultaneous edits will not happen, you can do something like the following:

```
cp -p /etc/sudoers /etc/sudoers.tmp
echo "%staff ALL=NOPASSWD: /sbin/shutdown" >> /etc/sudoers.tmp
if visudo -cqf /etc/sudoers.tmp; then
    mv /etc/sudoers.tmp /etc/sudoers
else
    rm /etc/sudoers.tmp
    echo "update failed"
fi
```

Comment: /etc has been (in 10.6 and in 10.7) a symlink to /private/etc, which is where sudoers is located. I've also tried specifying /private/etc/sudoers, but get the same result - the sudoers file opened, instead of edited.

Comment: Try running `echo "%staff ALL=NOPASSWD: /sbin/shutdown" >> /private/etc/sudoers` directly (of course, you probably need to be root).  If that works, replace the call to the script with that one-liner (i.e. remove the `if` around that command, including the unwanted branch.)

Comment: That works, but it's probably not super wise because it bypasses visudo. I haven't mentioned yet that we use Casper Suite to deploy all of this stuff, which runs all scripts as root, so that's no problem.

Comment: That's not my understanding. The else branch is what's run when this script is called as the editor via visudo.

Comment: Ah. It really is getting late. My last comment (deleted) was nonsense, sorry. >_>